# Most cost effective Google Cloud service for logging over HTTP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have an extremely simple use case: I have an app on my phone that regularly needs to submit HTTP requests to some server with a static IP/DNS, and these requests simply need to be stored to a log. I am sure this would be extremely easy to do using Cloud Compute instances, however I am wondering whether or not this is the most cost effective solution, since I don't need anything else than the ability to receive and store HTTP requests.

Does anyone know of a specific service that could be used to do this more cost effectively?

I tried using Firebase/Firestore and submitting documents using the REST API, but even this seems too cumbersome for my needs, I'm hoping there's something more streamlined.

Comment: Probably [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write).

Answer (score 1):

As **Ouroborus** suggested you can use **google cloud logging** for storing your logs. The **`Method: entries.write`** can be used along with **http request** for writing your **logs** to **cloud logging**. However you need to check whether you are following proper **structure** as mentioned in this [**official document**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write) provided by Ouroborus.

This is the request body structure provided in the official documentation mentioned above:

> ```
> {
>   "logName": string,
>   "resource": {
>     object (MonitoredResource)
>   },
>   "labels": {
>     string: string,
>     ...
>   },
>   "entries": [
>     {
>       object (LogEntry)
>     }
>   ],
>   "partialSuccess": boolean,
>   "dryRun": boolean
> }
> ```

If you feel sending logs by using **http requests** is a bit complicated you can also use **Cloud logging client libraries**, you can refer more about client libraries [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).